# Nested .click() trigger link needs to collapse main div

Tags: jquery, traversal

How do I collapse the div.collapse if I have the .click() trigger nested in another div (with the name div.click)?

I've got my script working if I have my .click() trigger in the same div as the div.collapse, this is my #main. Now I want to put my trigger in a div called 'click'. This is the structure I want to have:

```
<div id="main">    
    <div class="collapse" style="display:none;">
    my content
    </div>
    <div class="click">
    <a title="Click here to see the collapse div" alt="Expand" class="expand" href="javascript:void(0);">click here</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my jquery code so far, as I have no clue how to let it search one div back in the html structure:

```
  $jq("a.expand").click(function() 
  {  
    // hides matched elements if shown, shows if hidden 
    $jq("a.expand").prev("div.collapse")[o.method](o.speed); 
    $jq("a.expand").prev("div.collapse").prev()[o.method](o.speed); 

    return false;
  });
```

I hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: Not sure but I think previous refered to the previous sibling of `a.expand` wich does'nt exist. you should refer to the parent sibling.

Comment: Maybe something like `$jq("a.expand").parent().prev("div.collapse")[o.mthod](0.speed);`

Comment: the example you provided is one of the things I tried earlier, unfortunately without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$jq("a.expand").click(function(e)  {
    e.preventDefault();  
    // hides matched elements if shown, shows if hidden 
    $jq(this).parent().prev()[o.method](o.speed);
});
```

`$(this)` is the element that was clicked. `parent()` selects the immediate parent. `prev()` selects the sibling immediately preceding the target element. I also replaced your `return false;` with `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: But OP is using `return false`.  `e.preventDefault()` and `return false` are same right?

Comment: @user1671639 Not exactly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: Works for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/a4yr5/. Do you have your code wrapped in a ready handler, and are you sure `o.method` and `o.speed` are valid?

Comment: Very strange, on jsfiddle my code works fine.. this is my complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/9DJky/

Comment: Thanks Jason P, it works!
The jQuery library wasn't loading correctly. I fixed it and it works with using e.preventDefault.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use **[`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)**.

```
 $jq("a.expand").click(function() 
  {  
    // hides matched elements if shown, shows if hidden === Toggle
    $jq(".collapse").toggle(); 

    return false;
  });
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but I understand what .toggle() does. the thing is, the script works like a charm. it only brakes if I move the trigger click() to another div so I wonder what's the correct traversal to make it work again.